# PHP - Adicionar marca D'agua em um DOC ou PDF

Tags: php, pdf, documentação

Preciso que pegue meu documento .doc ou .pdf e adicione uma marca D`agua, pode ser também a marca "RASCUNHO" quando for visualizar.

O BO é o seguinte, preciso visualizar um documento mas precisa ter algo identificando que esse documento não é oficial, ou seja com alguma marca D'agua ou alguma informação no header da pagina escrito "rascunho, cópia não controlada..."

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Nos mostra o header que você já tem pra podermos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: olá, o header foi um exemplo, o que eu preciso é colocar uma mensagem no documento, tenho o documento salvo .doc ou .pdf, agora preciso adicionar a marca d'agua, vi algumas coisas sobre PHPWord, porem só encontrei para gerar o documento e não como adicionar no documento já existente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que é possível sem grandes problemas...

Para PDF, tem a biblioteca [PDF Watermarker](https://github.com/binarystash/pdf-watermarker). Exemplo de uso dela:

```
<?php
require_once('pdfwatermarker/pdfwatermarker.php');
require_once('pdfwatermarker/pdfwatermark.php');

//Specify path to image. The image must have a 96 DPI resolution.
$watermark = new PDFWatermark('C:\myimage.png'); 

//Set the position
$watermark->setPosition('bottomleft');

//Place watermark behind original PDF content. Default behavior places it over the content.
$watermark->setAsBackground();

//Specify the path to the existing pdf, the path to the new pdf file, and the watermark object
$watermarker = new PDFWatermarker('C:\test.pdf','C:\output.pdf',$watermark); 

//Set page range. Use 1-based index.
$watermarker->setPageRange(1,5);

//Save the new PDF to its specified location
$watermarker->savePdf(); 
?>
```

Para Word, achei no Github usando a biblioteca que mencionou, PHPWord. Só que não abriu nenhum arquivo para editar, não sei se isso seria difícil:

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';
// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
// Create header
$header = $section->createHeader();
// Add a watermark to the header
$header->addWatermark('_earth.jpg', array('marginTop'=>200, 'marginLeft'=>55));
$section->addText('The header reference to the current section includes a watermark image.');
// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Watermark.docx');
?>
```

**Fontes:**

- https://github.com/binarystash/pdf-watermarker
- https://github.com/tristanbes/PHPWord/blob/master/Examples/Watermark.php